# How do create a dynamic delay fix with MPEG-TS?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, video-streaming, mpeg

My media player can display a couple of videos (origin video - Multicast address, video stream is in MPEG-TS)

Whenever I play both video streams I see a delay in one of the streams.

I would like to create a delay fix that will sync both of the streams to the nearest timestamp, that way I would see in sync to what have happened at a delay of 3 sec for example.

The goal is to achieve sync in both streams and letting me know what is the delay between them.

Comment: Could you please specify whether you are operating on a Windows or Linux system? Additionally, if you are currently addressing this issue manually, could you provide insights into the manual steps you take for the fix? Understanding your manual approach can be valuable in establishing a starting point for devising dynamic logic adjustments aimed at achieving the desired synchronization goal. Oh, if you are using Windows, are you fine with solutions using PowerShell?